# I try to create basic trigger but return error 1064

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER inserccionSocio AFTER INSERT ON socio FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE anioInscripcion pago.anio%type;
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from fechaInscripccion) INTO anioInscripcion FROM socio WHERE id = :NEW.id; 
    INSERT INTO pago VALUES(NEW.id,anioInscripcion);
END;
//
```

I'm trying this trigger but return #1064 error.

> Something is wrong in your syntax near 'DECLARE anioInscripcion
> pago.anio%type; BEGIN
> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from ...' in the second line.

I use 10.4.27-MariaDB.

I look around `'DECLARE anioInscripcion pago.anio%type; BEGIN SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from ...' en la linea 2`

but i cant find mistakes.

Comment: Looks like a possible typo here: `anio%type`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `pago.anio%type;` be equal to a integer

And the method EXTRACT is collect in VARCHAR or in DATE, what I have done is saving them in VARCHAR instead of saving them in integer